# Getting user input using django forms.py return nothing

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to get the users input and add to a table in the database, everything goes smoothly with no errors .. but the input is not added to DB

**urls.py**

```
path('category/add/', views.add_cat, name="add_cat"),
```

**view.py**

```
def add_cat(request):
        # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CatForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            entry = Categories.objects.create(category_name=new_cat_name)
            entry.save()
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = CatForm()

    return render(request, 'add_cat.html', {'form': form})
```

**add_cat.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
{% load static %}
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in form %}
    <h3 align="center">{{ form.label }}</h3>
    <div align="center">{{ form }}</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 100px;"value="إضافة" />
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
{% load static %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in form %}
    <h3 align="center">{{ form.label }}</h3>
    <div align="center">{{ form }}</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 100px;"value="إضافة" />
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

change your form action, you were posting the data to '/' url but you need to put it in your add view

```
if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: That's is great ,it worked but  now i changed the variable to  `entry = Categories.objects.create(category_name=form)` adding the form to the end of the line, the whole HTML line for the form is added as str to database

Comment: check the edited ans, and dont forget to upvote and accept the ans if helped

Comment: returned the error  `'CatForm' object has no attribute 'save'
`

Comment: is your form a ModelForm or normal Form?

Comment: As I am very new to Django, if I get your question right. I think its normal form because it is not created from models.py, only the DB table did,
according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/ , it is normal form and i need to change it to model form